# Does ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate supports HierarchicalDataTemplate(WPF)?

Tags: wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate, contentpresenter, contenttemplate

I have gone through the HierarchicalDataTemplate in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netframework-4.8), in which it is mentioned that "DataTemplate that supports HeaderedItemsControl". From this point, I understood that HierarchicalDataTemplate is supported for the control which is derived from HeaderedItemsControl (That is to display collection of items).  Right?

Now, I just want to confirm that, is there any possible way to load HierarchicalDataTemplate as ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate(WPF) and display items in hierarchical way?

As like below code snippet

```
<ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            ..........
            ..........
            ..........
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: ContentPresenter does not derive from HeaderedItemsControl, at this point you might want to ask yourself why don't you follow the usual way of using it, e.g. TreeViewItem.

Comment: Some wpf controls have hard coded behavior built into them. I doubt hierarchicaldatatemplate has much if any that makes it dependent on a treeview. So I would expect it to work. Why don't you just try it with something simple and check it meets your expectations?